# How to Merge DB Schema containing SQLCMD variables

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

I am using Visual Studio 2015 (Enterprise) and a DB project. The compare I have set up compares my local DB with my local files which are under source control. This works fine for most files, but I have some SPs with SQLCMD variables which define the Database name, and I'm having trouble editing these SPs in a sensible way.

Here's an example of a statement in the SP on environment 1:

```
   SELECT T.SomeField1, T.SomeField2
   FROM   [LinkedServer].[Database1].dbo.SomeTable T
```

And that statement in the same SP residing on environment 2:

```
   SELECT T.SomeField1, T.SomeField2
   FROM   [LinkedServer].[Database2].dbo.SomeTable T
```

(The only difference is *Database1* vs *Database2*.)

And here's what the SP snippet looks like in the local file which is under source control:

```
   SELECT T.SomeField1, T.SomeField2
   FROM   [LinkedServer].[$(MySqlcmdVariable)].dbo.SomeTable T
```

The DB Project defines $(MySqlcmdVariable) differently depending on the environment.

I've tried a few different things that don't quite work:

1. Editing the SP directly within Visual Studio. The problem is that I can't execute the SP because it seems the SQLCMD variables don't work until you Update (from file to DB) or Publish to DB. This might work for minor changes, but for every day development of SPs I find this cumbersome.
2. Update the SP in SSMS and merge. This would be my preferred method, but I can't figure out a good way to merge the SQL changes in the DB back into the source file. When I do my DB Project compare, if the file is not modified, as expected, the comparison shows no differences despite the presence of the SQLCMD variables. But as soon as any change is made, the difference shows up, along with every SQLCMD variable present in the SP! (I feel like this is a bug in VS.) Now I can't update from DB to source because the SQLCMD variables would get overwritten. Note that updating from src to DB does work, but the change I want to keep is in the DB so I need to go the other way.
3. It would be nice if the compare tool had an editor so I can manually copy lines from one side to the other. Alternatively, it would be nice if I could use a custom compare tool like I can for comparing files under source control. I can't figure out how to use my preferred compare tool for a DB project when one of the sides is the DB.

What I've resigned to do for now is make changes in SSMS, then open my compare tool, copy the SP to one side and compare with the existing file, then manually merge in my changes. I'm convinced there has to be a better way though.

Comment: Do you have an example of the SP with the SQLCMD variable?  Personally, I'd just make the changes locally and copy them in. You can always save it to a file and use a diff tool to diff the proc file inside the project to the saved file as well, though that's some extra work.

Comment: @PeterSchott - I added some examples. Your suggestion sounds similar to what I'm currently doing, as outlined in the last paragraph. It's not that big of deal, especially since there are only a few SPs (out of thousands) that require the sqlcmd variables.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that. I think your best bet is just to manually update. You can always open the files side by side in notepad or some similar editor to catch all of the differences, but I don't know of a better way short of updating the project and then altering the text in the Proc to replace [Database1] with [$Database].

Comment: @PeterSchott - OK. Thx for confirming.